# Issue ngTagsInput AngularJs with "و" Persian Arabic char

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I use AngularJs ngTagsInput for taging system but when i want use some persian or Arabic char like "و" the tag closed and i can't use `و` char in my word like `سلام خوبی`.

I see we can write any "و" char in tag.

I test it this demo but i see have problem with this:
http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos

how can i do for fix this issue ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please can you edit your question to add exactly the text you used in the tag and any error messages you received?
See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Thanks

Comment: I edited my question